# TypeError: must be str, not NoneType .. building a calculator

Tags: python, calculator

```
# Calculator.py
from graphics import *
from button import Button

class Calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        win = GraphWin("Calculator")
        win.setCoords(0,0,6,7)
        win.setBackground("slategray")
        self.win = win

        self.__createButtons()
        self.__createDisplay()

    def __createButtons(self):
        bSpecs = [(2,1,"0"), (3,1,"."),
                  (1,2,"1"), (2,2,"2"), (3,2,"3"), (4,2,"+"), (5,2,"-"),
                  (1,3,"4"), (2,3,"5"), (3,3,"6"), (4,3,"*"), (5,3,"/"),
                  (1,4,"7"), (2,4,"8"), (3,4,"9"), (4,4,"<-"), (5,4,"C")]
        self.buttons = []

        for (cx, cy, label) in bSpecs:
            self.buttons.append(Button(self.win,Point(cx,cy),
                                       .75,.75,label))

        self.buttons.append(Button(self.win, Point(4.5,1),
                                   1.75, .75, "="))

        for b in self.buttons:
            b.activate()

    def __createDisplay(self):
        bg = Rectangle(Point(.5, 5.5), Point(5.5,6.5))
        bg.setFill("white")
        bg.draw(self.win)
        text = Text(Point(3,6), "")
        text.draw(self.win)
        text.setFace("courier")
        text.setStyle("bold")
        text.setSize(16)
        self.display = text



    def getButton(self):
        while True:
            p = self.win.getMouse()
            for b in self.buttons:
                if b.clicked(p):
                    return b.getLabel()

    def processButton(self, key):
        text = self.display.getText()
        if key == "C":
            self.display.setText("")
        elif key == "<-":
            self.display.setText(text[:-1])
        elif key == "=":
            try:
                result = eval(text)
            except:
                result = "ERROR"
            self.display.setText(str(result))
        else:
            self.display.setText(text+key)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            key = self.getButton()
            self.processButton(key)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    theCalc = Calculator()
    theCalc.run()
```

Hi, I'm new to Python and I tried to create this calculator, but i keep getting an error msg:

```
line 74, in <module>
    theCalc.run()
line 70, in run
    self.processButton(key)
line 65, in processButton
    self.display.setText(text+key)
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

I'd be glad if someone could explain to me what I did wrong..

Comment: Can you tell me how you installed the `button` package? I'd like to try out your code for myself.

Comment: Any error of the type `TypeError: must be ..., not NoneType` usually means that you're using the return value of a function that didn't return anything. If you look in `getButton` I think you'll find the problem.

Comment: I seems that your `key` parameter turns out to be `None` instead of a string.

Comment: I found the code, ran it, and, ecept for an indentation error, everything worked fine. Try copying and pasting the code you posted, as well as the code from http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/ppics1/code/chapter12/button.py 
 into a separate file called button.py, and try again

Comment: Again, running this code unedited works **totally** fine. If you still have errors, try redownloading the button.py script from [here](mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/ppics1/code/chapter12/button.py)

Comment: @LeviLesches you were right, i just forgot to return my getLabel() function in button.py! thank you all so much!